# Which versions of the Google Calendar API work with OAuth 2.0?

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-oauth

Since AuthSub is no longer working reliably, and along with OAuth 1.0 has been deprecated by Google for API Access, it seems that we'll have to upgrade our applications to support OAuth 2.0.  My question is, do we have to upgrade to v3 of the Calendar API to use OAuth 2.0?  Or can we use the older calendar APIs, V1 and/or V2 with OAuth 2.0?  We're using the google Java client libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest going ahead and upgrading to Calendar v3 at the same time as OAuth 2.0 since you'll probably need to move to the newer Google API libraries rather than the old GData library anyways. However, from a protocol standpoint (not necessarily from a library standpoint), all versions of the Google Calendar API should work with OAuth 2.0 tokens.